# Javascript - sum of string decimals

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration, decimal

i have and array of string that are decimals. I need to iterate the array and get the sum of them. For example

```
function check() {
    let arr = ["1,50", "1,50"];
    let sum1 = 0;
    let sum2 = "0";
    let sum3 = 0

    for (let i = 0, length = arr.length; i < length; i++) {
       sum1 += +arr[i];
       sum2 += +arr[i];
       sum3 +=  arr[i];  

    }
    console.log(sum1, sum2, sum3)
    //sum1 = NaN
    //sum2 = '0NaNNaN'
    //sum3 = 01,501,50
}
```

sum should be 3 or 3,00.

Comment: does array has commas instead of decimals

Comment: You need to use parseFloat()

Comment: Why does your number have `,` instead of `.`?

Comment: See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kyjph2o0/3/)

Comment: @user3696882  because my boss wonts to work with commas so...

Comment: @HassanImam I don't know Franco's intent but in Europe, or at least in the countries I deal with, they use write English traditional $1,000,000.00 as 1.000.000,00

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` for sum and `replace()` to replace `,` with `.`.

```js
let arr = ["1,50", "1,50"];
const result = arr.reduce((r, e) => r + +e.replace(',', '.'), 0)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I like it. Personally I prefer parseFloat() to omit units ['1.50$', '2.50$'].